# функция ofstream c++

Tags: c++, функции

Как реализовать чтобы при каждой новой итерации цикла с  функцией ofstream менялось название файла .txt.
Например:
1 итерация: Файл 1.txt;
2 итерация: Файл 2.txt;
3 итерация: Файл 3.txt;
и т. д.
То есть как при в место указания пути к файлу вставить переменную
//функция ofstream fout("Файл 1.txt");

Comment: что за каждая новая итерация ? итерация чего ?? и какую ещё переменную в названии файла - переформулируйте свой вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: @ampawd , переформулировал

Answer (score 3):

Пока ты не закрыл файл, переименовать его не получится. Только закрыть. Переименовать и заново открыть. 
Переименовывать через

```
int rename( const char * oldfilename, const char * newfilename );
```

Если я не правильно понял вопрос, то пиши в комменты. Вот ещё одно решение как я понял:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    std::string fname = "file"+std::to_string(i)+".txt";
    fstream file(fname.c_str());
    // work
}
```